# Manage data from .txt file to store it to SQLite3 in Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I need to store the data from a .txt file to a database in Sqlite3.

I first try to read the txt file:

```
f = open("path", 'r')
if f.mode=='r':
    content = f.read()
```

then i printed the "content" to know the structure of the data

```
print (content)

Rank   Male     Female 
1       Noah    Emma
2       Liam    Olivia
3       William Ava
4       Mason   Sophia
5       James   Isabella
```

How can i manage the data from the variable "content" to store it in a database with a table separated as rank, name and sex.

Comment: Please make some attempt at solving this yourself. There are plenty of guides available if you search online. Your code makes no use of `sqlite3` at all.

Comment: @IvanVinogradov CSV files are already list when you open them. TXT files are string

Comment: csv ant txt files are basically the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on manually inserting data from a text file, or you have no idea about what delimiters there are, you can do something like this:

```py
import sqlite3
    
# create in-memory db and connect
con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE t (col1, col2, col3);")  # use your column names here
    
# read data from file
f = open('<YOUR_FILE.TXT>', 'r')
cont = f.read()
f.close()
    
# format for inserting to db
rows = cont.split('\n')
rows = rows[1:]  # delete first row with captions
formatted = [tuple(x.split()) for x in rows]
    
# insert into db
cur.executemany("INSERT INTO t (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", formatted)
con.commit()
con.close()
```